# Is GPS inaccuracy consistent over short time spans?

Tags: algorithm, gps, indoor-positioning-system

I'm interested in developing a semi-autonomous RC lawnmower.

That is, the operator would decide when to stop, turn, etc., but could request "slightly overlap previous cut" and the mower would automatically do so. (Having operated high-end RC mowers at trade shows, this is the tedious part. Overcoming that, plus the high cost -- which I believe is possible -- would make a commercial success.)

This feature would require accurate horizontal positioning. I have investigated ultrasonic, laser, optical, and GPS. Each has its problems in this application. (I'll resist the temptation to go off on these tangents here.)

So... my question...

I know GPS horizontal accuracy is only 3-4m. Not good enough, but:

I don't need to know where I am on the planet. I only need to know where I am relative to where I was a minute ago.

So, my question is, is the inaccuracy consistent in the short term? if so, I think it would work for me. If it varies wildly by +- 1.5m from one second to the next, then it will not work.

I have tried to find this information but have had no success (possibly because of the ubiquity of other GPS-accuracy discussion), so I appreciate any guidance.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Edit ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

It's looking to me like GPS is not just skewed but granular. I'd be interested in hearing from anyone who can give better insight into this, but for now I'm going to explore other options.

I realized that even though my intended application is "outdoor", this question is technically in the field of "indoor positioning systems" so I am adding that tag.

My latest thinking is to have 3 "intelligent" high-dB ultrasonic (US) speaker units. The mower emits RF requests for a tone from each speaker in rapid sequence, measuring the time it takes to "hear" each unit's response, thereby calculating distance to each of these fixed point and using trilateration to get position. if the fixed-point speakers are 300' away from the mower, the mower may have moved several feet between the 1st and 3rd response, so this would have to be allowed for in the software. If it is possible to differentiate 3 different US frequencies, they could be requested/received "simultaneously". Though you still run into issues when you're close to one fixed unit and far from another. So some software correction may still be necessary. If we can assume the mower is moving in a straight line, this isn't too complicated.

Another variation is the mower does not request the tones. The fixed units send RF "here comes tone from unit A" etc., and the mower unit just monitors both RF info and US tones. This may simplify things somewhat, but it seems it really requires the ability to determine which speaker a tone is coming from.

Comment: I would say probably not. I use running tracking, and when the apps first came on the scene, my map would look like I was constantly zig-zagging across the trail. Over time they improved, but I assume that improvement was the software developers averaging and smoothing the data.

Comment: I think that GPS is not accurate enough for this. I would try a different approach. Look at this [wheel](https://www.amazon.com/Replacement-caster-assembly-iRobot-Roomba/dp/B06XDQQZ6Z). You can count the number of revolutions with IR led and a photodiode. You can use one with small diameter or one which is divided into more segments and get pretty good accuracy.

Comment: @Tim, that seems like meaningful empricial data, thanks.

Comment: @TDG, I believe you are saying I should keep track of distance and direction to know where I am, i.e., use dead reckoning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning). The trouble with that approach is the likelihood of wheel slippage.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the kind of thing you could (and should) measure empirically. Just set a GPS of your liking down in the middle of a field on a clear day and wait an hour. Then come back and see what you find.

Because I'm in a city, I can't run out and do this for you. However, I found a paper entitled [iGeoTrans – A novel iOS application for GPS positioning in geosciences](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261710565_iGeoTrans_-_A_novel_iOS_application_for_GPS_positioning_in_geosciences).

That includes this figure which duplicates the test I propose. You'll note that both the iPhone4 and Garmin eTrex10 perform pretty poorly versus the accuracy you say you need.

[image: GPS accuracy]

But the authors do some Math Magic™ to reduce the uncertainty in the position, presumably by using some kind of averaging. That gets them to a 3.53m RMSE measure.

If you have [real-time differential GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_GPS), you can do better. But this requires relatively expensive hardware and software.

Even aside from the above, you have the potential issue of GPS reflection and multipath error. What if your mower has to go under a deck, or thick trees, or near the wall of a house? These common yard features will likely break the assumptions needed to make a good averaging algorithm work and even frustrate attempts at DGPS by blocking critical signals.

To my mind, this seems like a computer vision problem. And not just because that'll give you more accurate row overlaps... you definitely don't want to run over a dog!

[image: GPSr]

Comment: thanks for this data! I only have a cheap Android phone and tried to find an app to log data such as you found online, which was looking like a fruitless search. I knew I could buy GPS breakouts and interface with an Arduino to log such data, but didn't want to waste time and money -- you've saved me both.  I've thought a lot about computer recognition, and haven't entirely ruled out having some big bold colorful targets that get recognized by the mower for positioning.

Comment: Also, recent pedestrian death c/o Uber self-driving cars aside, I do NOT intend to develop a fully autonomous item. The operator will have to keep his thumb on a button or it will immediately shut down. And trying to distinguish cut grass from uncut grass from a flower bed from the maintenance person's jacket from the pet guinea pig sounds **way** beyond current state of the art to me. I am thinking IR sensors giving "warm body ahead, override required" and of course pressure-sensitive bumpers.

Comment: @Tamias: I think the AndroSensor app might be helpful for testing. You can set a logging interval and have it record the results of any subset of sensors to a CSV file. It's nice for doing [quick science](http://richbits.rbarnes.org/counting-tree-rings.html).

Comment: @Tamias: Depending on what time of day you cut the grass, there may be a different IR signature for the freshly cut versus uncut. Or some other way to differentiate. It's certainly an interesting problem! If this answer's been helpful to you feel free to upvote it by clicking the up arrow or accept it by clicking the outline of a checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a standard GPS is no way accurate enough for this application.  A typical consumer grade receiver that I have used has a position accuracy defined as a CEP of 2.5 metres. This means that for a stationary receiver in a "perfect" sky view environment over time 50% of the position fixes will lie within a circle with a radius of 2.5 metres. If you look at the position that the receiver reports it appears to wander at random around the true position sometimes moving a number of metres away from its true location. When I have monitored the position data from a number of stationary units that I have used they could appear to be moving at speeds of up to 0.5 metres per second.  In your application this would mean that the lawnmower could be out of position by some not insignificant distance (with disastrous consequences for your prized flowerbeds).

There is a way that this can be done, as has been proved by the tractor manufacturers who can position the seed drills and agricultural sprayers to millimetre accuracy.  These systems use Differential GPS where there is a fixed reference station positioned in the neighbourhood of the tractor being controlled.  This reference station transmits error corrections to the mobile unit allowing it to correct its reported position to a high degree of accuracy.  Unfortunately this sort of positioning system is very expensive.

Comment: Since asking my question I have found other material about differential GPS but I thought this worth an upvote for it's helpful info.

Comment: I'm doing some research and planning some tests using ultrasound. "One way", not reflected. I'm willing to invest in components and time to try it out but trying to understand what parts to buy. I don't want to LRAD myself. I'm thinking 80db of 40 MHz. I should probably ask a new question with only the indoor-positioning tag, so I'll say thanks and goodby here.